# Changing Allowed HTML tags: @tags for help text input field

Tags: theming, input-formats

I want to display a simple table under a form field as part of the help text for that field (file field to be exact). Am I being totally mental or is there really no easy way of changing the allowed html tags for this text area? At the moment I have displayed:

`Instructions to present to the user below this field on the editing form.
Allowed HTML tags: a b big code del em i ins pre q small span strong sub sup tt ol ul li p br img`

If there is no easy way, what is the next easiest way of doing it?

UPDATE:

Clive came up with a great way of doing it below with a custom module. You can also add to this using ctools to make the help text collapsible as follows:

```
// Implement hook_field_widget_form_alter()
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, &$context) {
  // If some condition is matched based on the element provided...
  if (isset($element[0]) && $element[0]['#field_name'] == 'field_test') {
    // Alter the description using your more permissive set of tags
    $reworked = filter_xss($context['instance']['description'], _MYMODULE_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags());
    $element[0]['#description'] = theme('ctools_collapsible', array('handle' => 'Help text', 'content' => $reworked, 'collapsed' => TRUE));
  }
}

// Provide a more permissive set of tags to be used with filter_xss()
function _MYMODULE_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags() {
  // Merge the new set of allowed tags with the less permissive defaults
  $new_tags = array('table', 'thead', 'tbody', 'tfoot', 'tr', 'th', 'td');
  return array_merge(_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags(), $new_tags);
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a text field (title of question) or file field (description of question).

Comment: @7wonders What you added to the question would be good as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do it really, the list of allowed tags is hard coded into the [`_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags/7).

This is in turn called by [`field_filter_xss()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_filter_xss/7), not when the data is saved to the database but rather when it's displayed in [`field_default_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.form.inc/function/field_default_form/7).

Fortunately there is a way but it'll take a small custom module to do it. You're basically looking to implement a form alter hook for the field's widget form and set the element's description to use `filter_xss()` with a more permissive set of tags.

Something along these lines:

```
// Implement hook_field_widget_form_alter()
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, &$context) {
  // If some condition is matched based on the element provided...
  if (isset($element[0]) && $element[0]['#field_name'] == 'field_test') {
    // Alter the description using your more permissive set of tags
    $element[0]['#description'] = filter_xss($context['instance']['description'], _MYMODULE_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags());
  }
}

// Provide a more permissive set of tags to be used with filter_xss()
function _MYMODULE_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags() {
  // Merge the new set of allowed tags with the less permissive defaults
  $new_tags = array('table', 'thead', 'tbody', 'tfoot', 'tr', 'th', 'td');
  return array_merge(_field_filter_xss_allowed_tags(), $new_tags);
}
```

That's based on the premise that you only want to allow the new tags for an element called `field_test`, obviously if you want to do the same for other fields you'll need to change it to match a different condition. I advise using the excellent `dpm()` function included in the [`Devel module`](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to inspect object in your form alter function.

I've just tested the above and it works (I now have a table where my file field description would normally be), it feels a bit like a hack even though it technically sticks to the rules but hopefully it'll get you on the way.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Someone should definitely create a module to do this properly (how this cant be a core feature I don't know!).

Comment: @7wonders Yeah, definitely seems like an opportunity missed but I guess from the developers' points of view this would really have meant the field module maintaining its own text format and that might have been deemed overkill. A custom option to change it would have been nice though. I might turn this into a more useful module and post it on drupal.org actually, will keep you posted :)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Let me know when you got a sandbox up and I will happily test it for you.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using D6, you can navigate to /admin/settings/filter. There you need to click the "configure" option of "Filtered HTML". Then click on the configure tab. you will be presented with a text box labeled  "Allowed HTML tags". Enter the html tags that you need to use there.

In case of D7 go to admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html. Under Filter Settings, click on "Limit allowed HTML tags" tab. Enter the HTML tags you want  to use in the text box.

Comment: Im using D7 and trust me, that was the first thing I did and was shocked when it did not work! (yes I have cleared cache several times also). Its really baffling and seems to be the case on all help text fields for my site. Even if I add the allowed html filter to plain text and add the table tr td it does not work. Very annoying.

Comment: I just added a d7 fresh install and can confirm its default behaviour. It will not allow to change tags in the help section = madness! What hook can override this?

Comment: Try Setting "Full html" as a default input format and then check.

Comment: I can confirm that I was able to change the allowed tags for Filtered HTML with Drupal 7.10, and the filter worked as well as the 'allowed tags' display. So really aerozeppelin's answer is correct. :-)

Comment: But if you read the question Paul it is in regards to the allowed tags in the help text for a field so the answer is not correct.

Comment: Why create a custom module when you can follow the answer by aerozeppelin? It worked for me with Drupal 7. It worked great! Thanks